# symbolic matrix multiplication by Ryacas

Tags: r, matrix, symbolic-computation, yacas

I define two matrices `mat1` and `mat2` in `Sym` class which is suitable for Ryacas symbolic computation:

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")

mat1 <- List(
List(x, 2),
List(x^3, x))
```

and

```
mat2 <- List(
List(x, x),
List(3, 6 * x))
```

now the question is how I can have the symbolic multiplication of these two matrices  by Ryacas package?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a `yacas` question, not an `R` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> mat1 * mat2
expression(list(list(x^2 + 6, x^2 + 12 * x), list(x^4 + 3 * x, 
    x^4 + 6 * x^2)))
```